# Django Import Error, not work without django.bin

Tags: python, django, importerror

I have a probleme with the import. I learne from the Practical Django Projects.

The dir tree looks like in the site-packages/bin:

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───admin
│   └───flatpages
│       └───flatpage
│               change_form.html
│
├───cms
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__ 
│           settings.cpython-34.pyc
│           urls.cpython-34.pyc
│           wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│
├───search
│   │   admin.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
.....
```

When I want to import the search.models

```
from cms.models import SearchKeyword
```

The python don't find and I get ImportError, but

```
from django.bin.cms.models import SearchKeyword
```

works correctly.

Can someone explain this? I thought the first one also fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you adjust your project's settings.py's INSTALLED_APPS to declare cms?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.auth',
   '<path to cms typically mentioned in install doc>',
   ...
```

Comment: and if that's not it, there are TONS of search hits for 'django import error', so likely someone else has hit the same problem (lots of virtualenv related answers for example)

Comment: Yes, but I get the same, otherwise the cms is the project and the search just an app. And the second import resolve the first probleme, just I want to figure out how to work with the first.

Comment: Do other imports work in general for you?  I don't see cms/models.py and I see that Practical Django Projects is v 1.1 of Django.  I would expect, if SearchKeyWord was a class in search/models.py, to doing 'from search.models import SearchKeyWord' instead.  So, could it be that Django v1.1 vs the current v1.7 works differently and you need to take that into account while reading the book?  What if you open a shell by doing "python manage.py shell".  Can you import your model then?

Comment: The probleme is the PYTHONPATH, if I use the sys.path.insert('root/django/bin') and exit from shell, and starting again the path disappear. Is there any way to add path just to virtualenv?